# Fieldsets in Content Types

Tags: 7

How do you add a fieldset to a content type in Drupal 7 to group fields? I don't see this option anymore. I just want to group related fields on a form together. Will that also trigger vertical tabs instead of let fields just float around in the open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now its a separate module called [Field group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group). It comes with several display options including vertical tabs.